# Integrating storage migration for pallet-contracts

Tags: try-runtime, storage-migration

When integrating pallet-contracts v10 storage migration in `pub type Migrations`

```rust
use pallet_contracts::migration::{v10, v11, v12};
pub type Migrations = (
    v10::Migration<Runtime>,
)
```

I get an error about trait bounds not satisfied

> = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
> `(pallet_contracts::migration::v10::Migration<Runtime>,): OnRuntimeUpgrade`

First I thought this was a [duplicate][1] but my Cargo.toml `[try-runtime]` section already included the  `pallet-contracts/try-runtime` clause.

The first in a series of similar errors is:

```rust
  error[E0599]: the function or associated item `execute_block` exists for struct `Executive<Runtime, Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, ...>, ..., ..., ..., ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
     --> /home/simson/nodle/chain/runtimes/eden/src/lib.rs:237:15
      |
  237 |             Executive::execute_block(block)
      |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
      |
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/simson/nodle/chain/target/release/wbuild/runtime-eden/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/runtime_eden-709135493b42bf5f.long-type-12564475873963747691.txt'
      = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
              `(pallet_contracts::migration::v10::Migration<Runtime>,): OnRuntimeUpgrade`
```

The long type from the file above:

```rust
frame_executive::Executive<Runtime,

sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, 

polkadot_primitives::BlakeTwo256>, sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, 

RuntimeCall, 
MultiSignature, 
(CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, 
CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, 
CheckGenesis<Runtime>, 
CheckEra<Runtime>, 
CheckNonce<Runtime>, 
CheckWeight<Runtime>, 
ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>, 
ChargeSponsor<Runtime>)>>, 
ChainContext<Runtime>, 
Runtime,
(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_scheduler::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_reserve::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, 
pallet_reserve::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, 
pallet_reserve::Pallet<Runtime, Instance3>, 
pallet_grants::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_mandate::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, 
pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance3>, 
pallet_collator_selection::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_session::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_aura::Pallet<Runtime>, 
cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::Pallet<Runtime>, 
cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime>, 
parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>, 
cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, 
cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, 
cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, 
orml_xtokens::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_multisig::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_uniques::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_preimage::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_nodle_uniques::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_sponsorship::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_identity::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_allocations::Pallet<Runtime>, 
pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, 
pallet_reserve::Pallet<Runtime, Instance4>, 
pallet_contracts::Pallet<Runtime>), 
(pallet_contracts::migration::v10::Migration<Runtime>,)>
```

**What is the compiler trying to tell me here? What flag could be missing?**

*update*:

```rust
const TEST_ALL_STEPS: bool = cfg!(feature = "try-runtime");

pub type Migrations = (pallet_contracts::Migration<Runtime,TEST_ALL_STEPS>);
```

will not work as my migration is from 9 to 12

Comment: May I have the code link to reproduce this locally?

Comment: 1 minute I will branch and commit

Comment: @AurevoirXavier https://github.com/NodleCode/chain/tree/iso/stack10464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are multi-blocks migrations. You don't need to add all of them to the `Executive`.

You should add `pallet_contracts::Migration` to the `Executive` and configure:

```rs
impl pallet_contracts::Config {
    type Migrations = (
        pallet_contracts::migration::v10::Migration<Runtime>,
        pallet_contracts::migration::v11::Migration<Runtime>,
        pallet_contracts::migration::v12::Migration<Runtime>
    );
    ..
}
```

Please check the [documentation here.](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/4ac2db8095e55a68f9b3d843d4e4689759fcc9d5/substrate/frame/contracts/src/migration.rs#L18-L58)

Comment: but it does not make try runtime happy see my update above

Answer (score 1):

*[This answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/10482/116) is good, but some key parts to solve the problem is missing, they are added in this post*

Integration of pallet_contracts [multi-step mitigation](https://docs.rs/pallet-contracts/latest/pallet_contracts/migration/struct.Migration.html) is slightly different from integration of migrations intended to be executed in one block. Two steps are needed.

First in the block implementing `impl pallet_contracts::Config` for `Runtime` the step migrations should be added.

```rust
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Migrations = (
        pallet_contracts::migration::v10::Migration<Runtime>,
        pallet_contracts::migration::v11::Migration<Runtime>,
        pallet_contracts::migration::v12::Migration<Runtime>,
    );
}
```

Second in the `pallet_contracts::Migration<Runtime, TEST_ALL_STEPS>` must be integrated in `pub type Executive`

```rust
const TEST_ALL_STEPS: bool = cfg!(feature = "try-runtime");

pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
    (   pallet_contracts::Migration<Runtime, TEST_ALL_STEPS>,)
>;
```